# XML::Bare Can't locate object method "parse" via package "0"

Tags: xml, perl

I have a script as following,
is it asked to do in inside the `foreach` loop.
The script is as following,

```
use XML::Bare;

foreach my $i (1..100){
   my $xml=XML::Bare->new(
    file=>"/tmp/lcms$i.xml"
    );
    my %root=%{ $xml->parse() };
    #..do something with %root...
}
```

and when I try to run it I have the following error,

```
Can't locate object method "parse" via package "0" (perhaps you forgot to load "0"?) at telephone.pl line 8
```

I am relatively new to perl XML::Bare module and it would be great if someone would walk me through in this learning curve

Comment: You want us to explain what those two lines of code do? They create a new parser object to parse an XML file, where the name is dynamically created from the loop iteration variable. Then the file is parsed, and the returned hash reference is dereferenced into a new lexical hash variable. However, that's not an on-topic question on Stack Overflow. If you need to change that code, and you are having trouble doing that, please read [ask], try on your own first, and then post a new question explaining _what_ and _how_ you are trying to do, what the input and expected outcome is, and why.

Comment: Thanks, @simbabque and I edited my question with the error I get when I tried for myself . its a learning script

Comment: Ok now this is a different story. The error message means that your `$xml` variable (which was supposed to come out of `XML::Bare->new` is a literal zero `0`. Something went wrong when creating that object. First, use Data::Dumper to output it after it was created. Check what it says. Then verify that your XML::Bare is installed properly. Check which version you have. (`$ perl -MXML::Bare\ 99` on commandline, including the backslash-space). Also, why are you using XML::Bare? I've never heard of it before, and it's not been updated in nearly 5 years.

Comment: I would probably go with a different parser. From the little docs this XML::Bare looks a lot like XML::Simple, which also just parses XML into a data structure, but is very much discouraged, even by its maintainers, and not very popular around here. Maybe XML::Twig or XML::Compile are more suitable to your task. Whatever that is, you're not telling us.

Comment: I checked perl -MXML::Bare\ 99 on command line and it says as following, XML::Bare version 99 required--this is only version 0.53. well this is a test script I got from online which I need to fill in foreach loop after my %root =%{$xml->parse()}

Comment: So you have the newest version. Do you have 'use strict' and `use warnings` in your code? Do you know any Perl at all? A _test script_ doesn't tell us anything about what you are trying to achieve. And you haven't answered my question about why XML::Bare.

Comment: Yes I know Perl, basic and maybe a little more. No I do not have use warning in my code or use strict

Comment: Start by adding those two, then run again. My guess is you don't have the module installed properly. Might be it depends on some C library that's missing, and it doesn't error properly.

Comment: And you haven't answered my question about why XML::Bare-->This is what I have from online to start with as a part of academic interest someone sent me this. And I thought to look into it and understand it

Comment: No I installed the module using CPAN and it said OK as in, /usr/bin/make install  -- OK

Comment: You installed with `make`? Not with `cpan` directly? Should work, though uncommon. As a professional Perl developer, let me give you some advice. Don't invest time into an obscure library that is [hardly used anywhere](https://metacpan.org/requires/module/XML::Bare?sort=[[2,1]]). Instead, learn one of the big ones that people int he industry actually use, like [XML::Twig](https://p3rl.org/XML::Twig), [XML::Compile](https://p3rl.org/XML::Compile) or even pure [XML::LibXML](https://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160604/discussion-between-simbabque-and-user1017373).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently http://p3rl.org/XML::Bare returns 0 if a file was not found/could not be opened.
So the right way to handle this would be:

```
my $xml = XML::Bare->new(...) or die "Could not open file: $!";
```

Are you sure the files all exist?

Edit: As @simbabque suggested, I'd also recommend http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML

Comment: Thanks for the solution now the script runs, I would like to know what else I can do in the foreach loop, after the hash reference is dereferenced to the new lexical hash variable. i mean %root ?